# Qt negative int not rounding properly

Tags: qt, int, rounding

Using Qt, my negative int is not rounding properly. Here is my source code:

```
if (intCalibrate < 0)
{
    intCalibrateCalculate = (intCalibrate * 100.0f * 5.0f/9.0f - 0.5f) + 65535;
}
else
{
    intCalibrateCalculate = (intCalibrate * 100.0f * 5.0f/9.0f + 0.5f);
}
```

It is rounding correctly if it is positive. Not sure why negative isn't working.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: I mean -5.56 comes out to -5 when it should be -6.

Comment: Also, I said "not rounding", not "not working."

Comment: What does this have to do with Qt? It looks like standard C++ to me.

Comment: Well technically it was Qt, it just so happens that this chunk of code didn't use any Qt.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
if (intCalibrate < 0)
{
    intCalibrateCalculate = (intCalibrate * 100.0f * 5.0f/9.0f - 0.5f);
    intCalibrateCalculate = intCalibrateCalculate + 65535;
}
else
{
    intCalibrateCalculate = (intCalibrate * 100.0f * 5.0f/9.0f + 0.5f);
}
```